# GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

**Table_name**

```
ID | OCCUPATION | PROFESSION | YEAR | COUNTRY | CIPHER
------------------------------------------------------
1    BNG          A            2012     US       "200" 
2    RJH          A            2012     US       "100" 
3    ER           A            2012     US       "230" 
...
```

Obviously my SQL is not correct, but I'd like to do:

```
SELECT PROFESSION, YEAR, COUNTRY, GROUP_CONCAT(`CIPHER` separator `,`) 
from table_name 
GROUP BY COUNTRY,PROFESSION,YEAR
```

to get:

```
PROFESSION | YEAR | COUNTRY | CIPHER
--------------------------------------------
 A           2012     US      "200,100,230"
...
```

Basically I'd like to make groups with the same PROFESSION, YEAR and COUNTRY concatenating CIPHER and omitting the rest.

Comment: What is your current query? The one that gives you the top result set? Your suggested query looks correct.

Comment: I set up an sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c77b/2 your suggested query is correct.

Comment: I got the correct SQL. In PHPMyAdmin works: SELECT ID,COUNTRY,PROFESSION, YEAR,  GROUP_CONCAT(`cipher` separator ',') as `cipher` from Table_name group by  COUNTRY ,PROFESSION,YEAR

Comment: But in django breaks: Traceback ...   line 48, in post
    for temp in datas:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1565, in __iter__
    raise InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')
InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key

Comment: with Python 2.7.5, MySQL 5.5, Ubuntu, django 1.5.1 Any idea or post related?

Comment: SOLVED: the ID should't be in capital letters, it worked.ID->id THANK YOU!